# Using codeigniter, how to handle a method that's needed by numerous controllers/views?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Let's say I have a dropdown that gets its value from a DB table. For the sake of argument, let's keep it simple and use colors. I need to display the dropdown for a bunch of views from different controllers. I read a couple of blog posts where people use "helpers" while others initializes the controller's method. If it's a "generic" query such as this, where would one put code this method so that other controllers/views can access it?

Comment: If it's a database query, it should go where it's supposed to be: in the model; then call it anywhere you like. Or I just didn't understand the question, that might also be...If you talk about something common and equal for all methods, you could call it at constructor. Try to be more specific (make an example of some cases)

Comment: @rdlowrey what's the meaning of your comment? I mean, is it really appropriate here (and anywhere else)? I can see you're joking out of frustration, but _cui prodest_ ? Why here under a question which doesn't even imply the use of globals (which is not in the framework architecture. Well, sort of)?

Comment: @DamienPirsy I know, blatantly antagonistic :) I planned to delete it after a bit anyway, don't subsidize my immature comment with a reply ... (*clicking delete*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in a model and auto load it if you need it that often.  If there is a model that it fits into already, put it there.  Otherwise, there is nothing wrong with creating a new model to meet your needs.  Just try to keep things organized in a logical manner that meets your needs and makes it easy to track down the methods later.

Comment: Thank you. I used to put it inside the helper folder but I wasn't sure if it was the 'best practice.' How about creating a library? I didn't want to stick it inside one particular controller if other controllers need it.

Comment: I wouldn't create a library.  Just create a model file and change the "$autoload['model']" variable in autoload.php to have it available whenever you need it.

Comment: Why the heck didnt I think of that. LOL ... I was associating controllers to models and thought I needed a controller to go w/ the model. I forgot you can have a "generic" model, which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Hehe was just going to add that you don't need a controller for it :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317203/how-to-populate-dropdownlist-from-database-in-codeigniter) nails it:

> What I would do is create a function in my model, say $model->dropdown_options() and use that to get the rows from the database and put them into an array.

Then use the [Form Helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html) to generate the Dropdown.